# movement repeat in 2d game by opengl

Tags: c, opengl, glut, 2d-games

When the red car is moving, it is repeated with every movement and at every chance has repeated, I had searched but not found a solution, so what is the solution to the problem?

```
#include <GL\glut.h>
#define drawW 400
#define drawH 300
void reshape(int width, int height)
{

    glViewport(0, 0, width, height);
    glMatrixMode(GL_PROJECTION);
    glLoadIdentity();

    float ratio = (float)width / height;
    if (width > height)
    {
        glOrtho(-drawW * ratio, drawW * ratio, -drawH, drawH, -1, 1);
    }
    else
    {
        glOrtho(-drawW, drawW, -drawH / ratio, drawH / ratio, -1, 1);
    }
    glClear(GL_DEPTH_BUFFER_BIT);
    glClearColor(0.21, 0.22, 0.18, 1);
}
void car() {


    //drawing the movement car

    glTranslated(0, -100, 0);
    glBegin(GL_POLYGON);
    glColor3f(0.73, 0.63, 0.56);

    glVertex2f(50, 50);
    glVertex2f(0, 100);
    glVertex2f(-50, 50);
    glVertex2f(-50, -100);
    glVertex2f(50, -100);
    glEnd();

    //drawing the 1st wheel in the 1st quarter
    glBegin(GL_POLYGON);
    glColor3f(0, 0.0, 0);

    glVertex2f(75, 25);
    glVertex2f(50, 25);
    glVertex2f(50, 0);
    glVertex2f(75, 0);
    glEnd();

    //drawing the 2nd wheel in the 2nd quarter
    glBegin(GL_POLYGON);
    glColor3f(0, 0.0, 0);

    glVertex2f(-50, 25);
    glVertex2f(-75, 25);
    glVertex2f(-75, 0);
    glVertex2f(-50, 0);
    glEnd();

    //drawing the 3rd wheel in the 3rd quarter

    glBegin(GL_POLYGON);
    glColor3f(0, 0.0, 0);

    glVertex2f(-50, -50);
    glVertex2f(-75, -50);
    glVertex2f(-75, -75);
    glVertex2f(-50, -75);
    glEnd();


    //drawing the 4th wheel in the 4th quarter
    glBegin(GL_POLYGON);
    glColor3f(0, 0.0, 0);

    glVertex2f(75, -50);
    glVertex2f(50, -50);
    glVertex2f(50, -75);
    glVertex2f(75, -75);
    glEnd();
    glFlush();
}
void display()
{


    glClear(GL_COLOR_BUFFER_BIT);






    //drawing the green car in the 1st quarter
    glBegin(GL_POLYGON);
    glColor3f(0.28, 0.64, 0.47);

    glVertex2i(350, 300);
    glVertex2i(300, 300);
    glVertex2i(300, 150);
    glVertex2i(325, 125);
    glVertex2i(350, 150);
    glEnd();


    //drawing the 1st wheel of the car
    glBegin(GL_POLYGON);
    glColor3f(0, 0, 0.0);

    glVertex2i(300, 275.0);
    glVertex2i(283, 275);
    glVertex2i(283, 250);
    glVertex2i(300, 250.0);
    glEnd();


    //drawing the 2nd wheel of the car
    glBegin(GL_POLYGON);
    glColor3f(0, 0, 0.0);

    glVertex2i(300, 200.0);
    glVertex2i(283, 200);
    glVertex2i(283, 175);
    glVertex2i(300, 175.0);
    glEnd();


    //drawing the 3rd wheel of the car
    glBegin(GL_POLYGON);
    glColor3f(0, 0, 0.0);

    glVertex2i(365, 200);
    glVertex2i(350, 200);
    glVertex2i(350, 175);
    glVertex2i(365, 175);
    glEnd();

    //drawing the 4th wheel of the car
    glBegin(GL_POLYGON);
    glColor3f(0, 0, 0.0);

    glVertex2i(365, 275);
    glVertex2i(350, 275);
    glVertex2i(350, 250);
    glVertex2i(365, 250);
    glEnd();
    glFlush();



    //drawing the purple car 
    glBegin(GL_POLYGON);
    glColor3f(0.48, 0.48, 0.64);

    glVertex2i(-350, 300);
    glVertex2i(-300, 300);
    glVertex2i(-300, 150);
    glVertex2i(-325, 125);
    glVertex2i(-350, 150);
    glEnd();

    //drawing the 1st wheel of the car
    glBegin(GL_POLYGON);
    glColor3f(0, 0, 0.0);

    glVertex2i(-300, 275.0);
    glVertex2i(-283, 275);
    glVertex2i(-283, 250);
    glVertex2i(-300, 250.0);
    glEnd();


    //drawing the 2nd wheel of the car
    glBegin(GL_POLYGON);
    glColor3f(0, 0, 0.0);

    glVertex2i(-300, 200.0);
    glVertex2i(-283, 200);
    glVertex2i(-283, 175);
    glVertex2i(-300, 175.0);
    glEnd();


    //drawing the 3rd wheel of the car
    glBegin(GL_POLYGON);
    glColor3f(0, 0, 0.0);

    glVertex2i(-365, 200);
    glVertex2i(-350, 200);
    glVertex2i(-350, 175);
    glVertex2i(-365, 175);
    glEnd();

    //drawing the 4th wheel of the car
    glBegin(GL_POLYGON);
    glColor3f(0, 0, 0.0);

    glVertex2i(-365, 275);
    glVertex2i(-350, 275);
    glVertex2i(-350, 250);
    glVertex2i(-365, 250);
    glEnd();


    //the break
    glBegin(GL_POLYGON);
    glColor3f(0.0, 0, 0.0);

    glVertex2i(-300, 100);
    glVertex2i(-300, 75);
    glVertex2i(-150, 100);
    glVertex2i(-150, 75);

    glEnd();


    //drawing the line in the middle of the road
    glBegin(GL_POLYGON);

    glColor3f(30, 30, 0);

    glVertex2f(20, 200);
    glVertex2f(-20, 200);
    glVertex2f(-20, 50);
    glVertex2f(20, 50);
    glEnd();




    //drawing the red object of the car
    glTranslated(0, -100, 0);
    glBegin(GL_POLYGON);
    glColor3f(0.91, 0.07, 0.09);

    glVertex2f(50, 50);
    glVertex2f(0, 100);
    glVertex2f(-50, 50);
    glVertex2f(-50, -100);
    glVertex2f(50, -100);
    glEnd();

    //drawing the 1st wheel in the 1st quarter
    glBegin(GL_POLYGON);
    glColor3f(0, 0.0, 0);

    glVertex2f(75, 25);
    glVertex2f(50, 25);
    glVertex2f(50, 0);
    glVertex2f(75, 0);
    glEnd();

    //drawing the 2nd wheel in the 2nd quarter
    glBegin(GL_POLYGON);
    glColor3f(0, 0.0, 0);

    glVertex2f(-50, 25);
    glVertex2f(-75, 25);
    glVertex2f(-75, 0);
    glVertex2f(-50, 0);
    glEnd();

    //drawing the 3rd wheel in the 3rd quarter

    glBegin(GL_POLYGON);
    glColor3f(0, 0.0, 0);

    glVertex2f(-50, -50);
    glVertex2f(-75, -50);
    glVertex2f(-75, -75);
    glVertex2f(-50, -75);
    glEnd();


    //drawing the 4th wheel in the 4th quarter
    glBegin(GL_POLYGON);
    glColor3f(0, 0.0, 0);

    glVertex2f(75, -50);
    glVertex2f(50, -50);
    glVertex2f(50, -75);
    glVertex2f(75, -75);
    glEnd();








    glFlush();
}

void processNormalKeys(unsigned char key, int x, int y)
{
    switch (key)
    {
    case 'd':
    case 'D':
        glTranslated(200, 100, 0);
        car();
        glutPostRedisplay;
        break;
    case 'a':
    case 'A':
        glTranslated(-200, 100, 0);
        car();
        break;

    }
}

int main(int argc, char** argv) {
    glutInit(&argc, argv);


    glutInitWindowSize(1000, 600);
    glutCreateWindow("Speedy Car Race");
    glutSwapBuffers;
    glutDisplayFunc(car);
    glutPostRedisplay();

    glutDisplayFunc(display);
    glutKeyboardFunc(processNormalKeys);
    glutReshapeFunc(reshape);
    
    glutMainLoop();
    return 0;
}
```

I try adding glutSwapBuffer(), glutPostRedisplay(), glClear(GL_COLOR_BUFFER_BIT)

but not of them working?

Comment: "it is repeated with every movement and at every chance has repeated" I don't understand what you mean.

Answer (score 3):

This line **DOES NOT** call `glutPostRedisplay`:

```
    glutPostRedisplay;
```

Therefore your keyboard events do not trigger the `display()` function, `glClear` isn't called, and the buffer isn't cleared.

To actually call `glutPostRedisplay`, you must put parentheses after the function name:

```
    glutPostRedisplay();
```